# How to sort a dictionary based on its key values

Tags: python

I have a dictionary like the following:

```
{2234:A0,432:A16,3336:A0,11:A0,3:A16}
```

and I want to sort the dictionary based on its keys like the following:

```
{3:A16,11:A0,432:A16,2234:A0,3336:A0}
```

Here is what I have tried but it doesn't sort the dictionary.

```
sorted(a_dict.items())
print(a_dict)
```

Answer (score 0):

Sort it by key first, and then integer part of the value  next , example:

```
dict(sorted(sorted(d.items()), key= lambda x: int(x[1][1:]), reverse=True))
```

Gives

```
{3: 'A16', 432: 'A16', 11: 'A0', 2234: 'A0', 3336: 'A0'}
```